# Do user computers of a java program need to have JAVA_HOME environment variable set or only while developing and compiling?

Tags: java-home

I am just getting started on a java program and wanted to know when I complete the program will the client/user computers of my java executable need to have the Java_home variable set or is this only for the development environment.

Comment: Totally depends on the application. Some do and some don't.

Comment: how will you know if they do need it?

Comment: The docs will tell you.

Comment: The docs?  If I am the developer and I just want to know if my user will have to set up Java_Home how will I know?  the docs of the libraries I use?